# keeping track of online user using phone number

Tags: android

I am developing android application in which want to keep track of online users.
When the user install the app, he gives his number and country code, we register the user with that number.
Now whenever he starts the application he sends the list of all mobile contacts to server to find who is online.

The problem with this approach is same mobile number can be in different format like

- +91 9665123456
- 91 9665123456
- 0 9665123456
- 9665123456

Lets assume while registering the user A gave number +91 9665123456 and we register the user and make it online whenever the app is running.
But in user B mobile, his number is stored as 09665123456, I need to query whether user A is online or not, but as both number are different what approach to use ?
I am not sure how whatsapp approaches to this problem?
The other way what I can think of is using [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) to find the number match but it also gives probability.
Is there any other approach which is recommended to handle above scenario ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general programming approach, and not code-based. It will elicit opinion-based answers, and is better suited to a different stackexchange forum, perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a below approach:

1, Your server should have a list of country codes and the corresponding number of digits allowed for a mobile number in that country

2, When the registered user A , comes online and sends his contacts to your server for the first time, you can check a contact by starting from the left end of the number. If you see a international prefix 00 or +, then take the first digit from left, identify the country code and if the remaining number of digits to the right match the defined number of digits for this country , scan the list of users registered with that country code to see a match. If no, then take the first 2 digits to see for a possible country code and check similarly. 
Now if you dont see any international prefixes in a contact, that means the contact is in the same country as A and so you need to scan the list of users registered from the same country after taking the last certain number of digits as required for that country code.

3, It will be better if you generate a unique id for a  each registered user which can be used as a primary key for a user database. This will eliminate the need for detailed scan for repeat users. For eg: let A have an id 123 and B have an id 456. When A logs in, set the online flag for A , then search for B and if B is already registered, then add B's id 456 to A's friends list along with corresponding number stored by A. So next time when A comes in, you will see that contact B has a unique ID assigned and so you need to go check if the online flag is set for this ID. Also this will be useful even if a user changes his/her number

Comment: Prefix 00 is the international prefix for India, how to make it generic for the US whose prefix is 011 or other countries whose prefix  may be different ? How could you say that 00 is international prefix for every country?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while developing an app. What you can do here is, to check the input for special characters, and also take the size in account. Remove the spaces, and store just the last 10 digits. This can be achieved by trimming and subString operations, if the entry type is a string. Then comparison of the two strings should result in a desired manner.

Comment: Considering only last 10 digit, it may possible that two country can have same number with different country code, and it can also be possible that some country phone number are not even of 10 digits. In that case how to tackle problem?

Comment: If user A wants to see if user B is online or not, it'll just depend on user A's style of storing the contact in his phonebook. You can simply store the last 10 digits, and use the user-id and phone-number as a combined "primary-key" when you query the 'online' activity. Also, if IM is to be implemented, let it depend on user's style of storing the number, the message delivery is his resp.

Comment: If user A wants to know how many of his contacts are online, he sends the list of phone numbers to the server and server return the sublist of online contacts. This will work if both phone have same format.
How can user A send the user-id of user B because user A only has his user-id. The contact name may differ in both phone?
And other question remain unanswered if phone number are less than 10 digits, how to tackle ?

Comment: I tackled the problem of less than 10 digits by ignoring them, as they're not personal contacts. Most of them are system-contacts (SIM). About ids, dude you have to store contacts of user A and B on server database, and compare the last 10 digits. You have ids of both users on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

as per my suggestion

==> first of all you remove all space in your number using replace(" ","") function,

==> then use query for match last 10 character so its give you mobile number which you have want to find is there online or offline from users Contact book.

Comment: What if the phone number is less than 10 digits ?